# How do you get this drop down selection in VS code when doing a Flutter/Dart project?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

[Screenshot of "right-click"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Cq2d.png)[Image from VScode screenshot from project[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uem3C.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvz3s.png)

Just highlight it and the lightbulb next to it shows up and once you click that then the drop down shows.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just right-click on the widgets. Where is the problem with this question?

Comment: Check updated image.  This is what 'right-click' shows on Mac.